# Setting Raspberry GPIO value in rc.local

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi

I'm a semi-linux newcomer and i have a question:

I need to set some GPIO pins in this way: (pin 18 out, pin 17 in) (actually i'm doing this via WiringPi(python) trought this commands)

```
gpio export 18 out

gpio export 17 in
```

All Works fine if i run these commands via terminal. However i have set these commands in

```
/etc/rc.local
```

before `exit 0`

to run it at boot, but after some tryies it won't work. It could be a path problem? 
Any help is appreciated, Thanks mboy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed it! All I needed was to set the full path.

In my case `/usr/local/bin/gpio export 18 out` because `gpio` is a third party command.